# pandas if else conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

suppose i have below df:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dic = {
    "a": [0,0,1,2],
    "b": [0,3,4,5],
    "c": [6,7,8,9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  0  6
1  0  3  7
2  1  4  8
3  2  5  9
```

I need to past value to new column from above columns based on conditions:

```
if df.a > 0 then value df.a
else if df.b > 0 then value df.b 
else value df.c
```

For now i try with:

```
df['value'] = [x if x > 0 else 'ww' for x in df['a']]
```

but don't know how to input more conditions in this.

Expected result:

```
   a  b  c value
0  0  0  6  6
1  0  3  7  3
2  1  4  8  1
3  2  5  9  2
```

Thank You for hard work.

Comment: This is definitely NOT the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659 as marked above. This question asks how to use a default value that is from an existing column which was what I was looking for. The other question uses a pre-defined set of choices based on the condition which didn't help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['value'] = np.select([df.a > 0 , df.b > 0], [df.a, df.b], default=df.c)
print (df)
   a  b  c  value
0  0  0  6      6
1  0  3  7      3
2  1  4  8      1
3  2  5  9      2
```

Difference between vectorized and loop solutions in 400k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [158]: %timeit df['value2'] = np.select([df.a > 0 , df.b > 0], [df.a, df.b], default=df.c)
9.86 ms ± 611 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [159]: %timeit df['value1'] = [x if x > 0 else y if y>0 else z for x,y,z in zip(df['a'],df['b'],df['c'])]
399 ms ± 52.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I knew the numpy way would be faster, that is a lot lot lot faster even in a small df

Answer (score 6):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
df['value'] = [x if x > 0 else y if y>0 else z for x,y,z in zip(df['a'],df['b'],df['c'])]
```

Comment: Thank You for nice solution

Comment: It is intuitive however the answer from @jezrael is a lot better performance-wise, so please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that takes a row in as a parameter, tests whatever conditions you want to test, and returns a `True` or `False` result - which you can then use as a selection tool. (Though on rereading of your question, this may not be what you're looking for - see part 2 below)

**Perform a Selection**

`apply` this function to your dataframe, and use the returned series of True/False answers as an index to select values from the actual dataframe itself.

e.g.

```
def selector(row):
    if row['a'] > 0 and row['b'] == 3 :
        return True
    elif row['c'] > 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can build whatever logic you like, just ensure it returns True when you want a match and False when you don't.

Then try something like

```
df.apply(lambda row : selector(row), axis=1)
```

And it will return a Series of True-False answers. Plug that into your df to select only those rows that have a `True` value calculated for them.

```
df[df.apply(lambda row : selector(row), axis=1)]
```

And that should give you what you want.

**Part 2 - Perform a Calculation**

If you want to create a new column containing some calculated result - then it's a similar operation, create a function that performs your calculation:

```
def mycalc(row):
    if row['a'] > 5 :
        return row['a'] + row['b']
    else:
        return 66
```

Only this time, `apply` the result and assign it to a new column name:

```
df['value'] = df.apply( lambda row : mycalc(row), axis = 1)
```

And this will give you that result.